# Android Studio: Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Someone else occupies parameter's slot at 2 error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, code-generation, kotlin-coroutines

How can I solve this error

I have updated the kotlin version, still not solving the error.
I have also invalidate cache but error still persist.

e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node:

I don't know if this is a gradle issue or kotlin issue.

Any one has an approach to solve this build issues?

```
    File is unknown
The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.fixRangeOfLvtRecord(CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.kt:335)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:813)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.DeferredMethodVisitor.visitEnd(DeferredMethodVisitor.kt:31)
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.AnonymousObjectTransformer.inlineMethodAndUpdateGlobalResult(AnonymousObjectTransformer.kt:265)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.AnonymousObjectTransformer.doTransform(AnonymousObjectTransformer.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner$doInline$lambdaInliner$1.handleAnonymousObjectRegeneration(MethodInliner.kt:192)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner$doInline$lambdaInliner$1.anew(MethodInliner.kt:216)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.commons.InstructionAdapter.visitTypeInsn(InstructionAdapter.java:472)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.TypeInsnNode.accept(TypeInsnNode.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(InsnList.java:144)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:792)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:370)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.inlineCall(InlineCodegen.kt:251)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:146)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiInlineCodegen.genCallInner(PsiInlineCodegen.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultImpls.genCall(CallGenerator.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiInlineCodegen.genCall(PsiInlineCodegen.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2656)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2598)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:393)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:374)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1760)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:639)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:467)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:249)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.gen(FunctionCodegen.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genSimpleMember(MemberCodegen.java:196)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassBodyCodegen.java:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:301)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:285)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:616)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:203)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:346)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:240)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:601)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Someone else occupies parameter's slot at 2
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.fixRangeOfLvtRecord(CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.kt:335)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.fixLvtForParameters(CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.kt:329)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.performTransformations(CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.kt:201)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:70)
    ... 91 more

Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Someone else occupies parameter's slot at 2
```

Here is the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
   classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10"
}
```

The errors are thrown whenever I tried to compile the code

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node:
emit (Ljava/lang/Object;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;:
```

Comment: Have you updated coroutines library to [recommended version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details)?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sir!
I have solved my problem by the short dependencies that you have put in the above. I have also used other solutions which were described by other developers, for instance by

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED

in the gradel.properties . But one of my apps was extremely difficult to solve its problem. And I took your techniques to solve it. So now all of them are alright. Thanks

Comment: Pardon me, but it's not clear (to me) whether your answer solves the problem described in the question. By the way, I suggest that you learn about [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).